# Is it possible that we override global variables?

Tags: matlab

I have this function:

```
function example(y)
global TICTOC;
tic
TICTOC=5;
toc
end
```

and I expect *TICTOC=5* change the result of *toc*, since *TICTOC* is a global variable in tic and toc functions; but this is not the case; Does anyone know the reason?

I like to know the answer, because I 'm worried to declare a global variable, which it's name has been declared global in some other functions, I'm not aware of.

I saw this function in matlab 2008b help

```
function tic
%    TIC Start a stopwatch timer.
%        TIC; any stuff; TOC
%    prints the time required.
%    See also: TOC, CLOCK.
global TICTOC
TICTOC = clock;

function t = toc
%    TOC Read the stopwatch timer.
%    TOC prints the elapsed time since TIC was used.
%    t = TOC; saves elapsed time in t, does not print.
%    See also: TIC, ETIME.
global TICTOC
if nargout < 1
    elapsed_time = etime(clock, TICTOC)
else
    t = etime(clock, TICTOC);
end
```

thanks.

Comment: euhm...what Matlab version do you have? TICTOC has been a built-in function at least since R2010b (meaning, no Matlab-accessible global variables)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but I the answer of my question is No. I checked it and it seems that it is not being overwritten. The reason must be because tic, toc is a built in Matlab function

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use assignin command to send the TICTOC value to base and thus changing the global value.
I use the assignin command to send parameters from function to Base.

Regards
Dilip